# ZMQ: REQ/REP fails with multiple concurrent requests and polling

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have run into a strange behaviour with ZeroMQ that I have been trying to debug the whole day now.

Here is a minimal example script which reproduces the problem. It can be run with Python3.

One server with a REP socket is started and five clients with REP sockets connect to it basically simultaneously. The result is that the server starts to block for some reason after the first few messages. It seems like the `poller.poll(1000)` is what blocks indefinitely.

This behavior also seems to be timing-dependant. Insert a `sleep(0.1)` in the loop that starts the clients and it works as expected.

I would have expected the REP socket to queue all incoming messages and release them one after the other via `sock.recv_multipart()`.

What is happening here?

```py
import logging
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import zmq

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
PORT = "3446"
stop_flag = False

def server():

    logging.info("started server")
    context = zmq.Context()
    sock = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    sock.bind("tcp://*:" + PORT)
    logging.info("bound server")

    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(sock, zmq.POLLIN)

    while not stop_flag:

        socks = dict(poller.poll(1000))
        if socks.get(sock) == zmq.POLLIN:

            request = sock.recv_multipart()
            logging.info("received %s", request)
            # sleep(0.5)

            sock.send_multipart(["reply".encode()] + request)

    sock.close()

def client(name:str):
    context = zmq.Context()
    sock = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    sock.connect("tcp://localhost:" + PORT)
    sock.send_multipart([name.encode()])
    logging.info(sock.recv_multipart())
    sock.close()

logging.info("starting server")
server_thread = Thread(target=server)
server_thread.start()
sleep(1)

nr_of_clients = 5
for i in range(nr_of_clients):
    Thread(target=client, args=[str(i)]).start()

stop_flag = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem seems to be that you are "shutting down" the server before all clients have received their reply. So I guess its not the server who's blocking but clients are.

You can solve this by either waiting some time before you set the `stop_flag`:

```
sleep(5)
stop_flag = True
```

or, better, you explicitely join the client threads like:

```
nr_of_clients = 5
threads = []
for i in range(nr_of_clients):
    thread = Thread(target=client, args=[str(i)])
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

stop_flag = True
```